# Did Jaques Chirac say “Without Africa, France will slide down into the rank of a third [rate] power”?

Tags: france, colonization, africa

This [article claims](http://www.siliconafrica.com/france-colonial-tax/) that Jaques Chirac stated in March 2008:

> “Without Africa, France will slide down into the rank of a third [rate] power”

This is significant because it implies France is acting like a 19th century colonial power.

My question is: **Did Jaques Chirac say “Without Africa, France will slide down into the rank of a third [rate] power”?**

Comment: This is a repost of the same conspiracy theory as your [last question](http://history.stackexchange.com/questions/18984/does-it-impair-frances-moral-credibility-that-it-is-a-19th-century-style-coloni).

Comment: I don't think this possible quote as such does/would imply that "France is acting like a 19th century colonial power".

Comment: The idea that that France finances 40% of its budget from taxing African nations, and nobody except this one article noticed, is somewhat ludicrous.

Comment: Why is the word "world" in square brackets? Not just here, but also in the other citations on the internet? What is Chirac supposed to have said? Does "a third power" make any sense? Presumably he said it in French? Can anyone quote the French "original"?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have found it now here: http://www.diplomatie.gouv.fr/fr/IMG/pdf/24_Lombart.pdf (footnote 40), where someone (not Chirac himself) says that Chirac is “de ceux pour qui ‘sans l’Afrique, la France deviendrait une puissance de troisième rang’” (one of those for whom “without Africa France would become a third-rate power”). NB. "third rate" not "third world".

Comment: The footnote points to *Le Monde diplomatique* which I would guess was no friend (since politically to the left of) Chirac the castle owner, etc.

Comment: Could you expand on that? Does this mean Chirac didn't say it, or that he did say it but he is not the source going on record?

Comment: Unfortunately, this is all the information I have. The speech marks around 'sans l'Afrique .... rang' indicate that it is a quotation from someone, but it is not clear whether it is a quotation from Chirac.